# jQuery.Ajax: $.get and document.write replace existing markup

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get

I recently found out a method to include the content of an external file into the website using jQuery Ajax.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.get("http://something.com/content.txt", function(a) {
    document.write("<p>Some text! - " + a + "</p>")
  });
</script>
```

The output will be following then:

```
<p>Some text! - Content from external file</p>
```

It works fine except that this code is overwriting the entire markup. Everything else will be excluded.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` will replace all contents.

You're using jQuery so try `.append()` if you want to keep existing code, like this:

```
$.get("http://something.com/content.txt", function(a) {
  $("#element-where-inserting").append(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope your modifications to a specific selector in your document, if using jquery and and assuming you have a `div` with id `mycontent` and content of file is plain text:

```
$("#mycontent").text(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `document.write()` method rewrites the whole html document.

What you should do instead is find the element where you want to put the content of your response via javascript (use the `html()` method since you're using jQuery):

```
$("#elementId").html(response);
```

where `response` is your ajax content.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$([some element]).load([your URL])` this will load the data you have received and put it inside of the intended element.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $('some-div').load("http://something.com/content.txt")

</script>
```